# RS232 and RS422 (Isolated and ESD Protected)

Tags: rs232, opto-isolator, isolation, rs422

I want my RS232 and RS422 to be galvanically isolated and ESD protected. I have two options to implement this requirement.

---

Option 1: MCU-->OPTO-->DRIVER-->ESD PROTECTION

Use [MAX3232](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf) for RS232 driver with [ESD diodes](http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/sdc15.pdf) near the connector and lines connecting to MCU I will isolate using optocoupler [ACPL-217](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-0470EN). Next, for power supply I will have to use transformer driver say [MAX253CSA](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX253.pdf) or [SN6501](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn6501.pdf) with transformers.

Use similar type of set-up for RS422 with [MAX489](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf), optocoupler and transformer driver.

---

Option 2: MCU-->ISOLATED DRIVER-->ESD PROTECTION

Use [MXL1535E](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3535E-MXL1535E.pdf) for RS422, with external transformer only(transformer driver is inbuilt) to implement the design. No ESD diodes also, since it is +15KV ESD protected.

Use [MAX3250](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3535E-MXL1535E.pdf) for RS232 interface, with ESD diodes also.

---

Looking into space constraint option 2 looks better with fewer components, but please suggest your views which option is better for the good and robust design?

Comment: If space is an issue, maybe check out Analog Devices isolators. Some, like ADM2687E, have integrated DC-DC converters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A design I have used for a while now and that seems to work very well, is to use TI ISO7221A for UART (TTL) isolation, and then a driver on the nonisolated side, i.e. MCU->ISO7221->driver. I use this with an FTDI FT231 virtual serial driver, but if you prefer bare RS232 you can just use a MAX3232 instead.

The advantage of this design is that it is a fair bit cheaper than using one of your isolated drivers, while still getting well-defined performance (contrary to using a bare photoisolator).

For isolated power I default to those SIP 5V to 5V isolated supplies, e.g. XP Power or TracoPower TMA0505S. Make sure you filter these puppies really well - at least a big (>100µF) bulk electrolytic capacitor, but preferably a full common-mode filter (CM choke + 2 capacitors). Unfiltered these little power supplies kick out horrible amounts of EMI.

As ESD protection I usually just stick with simple BAT54S clamping to the ground and Vcc: cheap and cheerful. Make sure to put a nice big zener on the power lines as well, as close to possible ESD sources and clamping diodes as possible, with nice fat traces.

Comment: And what power supplies can be from XPPOWER?

Comment: @AKR: for instance IB0505S, but you can look at the manufacturer catalogue or do a selection on one of the popular distributors (Farnell/MCM/Newark/Element14, Digikey, RS Components, Mouser) to see which fits your purpose best.